# Overriding operator>> for a Strings class

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, istream

I just have a quick question. I need to override the operator >> for a custom String class and I can't quite figure out how to do it.

I know that this code works, because it was my original method of solving the problem:

```
istream& operator>>(istream &is, String &s) {
  char data[ String::BUFF_INC ];  //BUFF_INC is predefined
  is >> data;
  delete &s;
  s = data;
  return s;
}
```

However, according to the spec (this is a homework assignment), I need to read in the characters 1 at a time to manually check for whitespace and ensure that the string isn't too big for data[]. So I changed my code to the following:

```
istream& operator>>(istream &is, String &s) {
  char data[ String::BUFF_INC ];
  int idx = 0;
  data[ 0 ] = is.get();
  while( (data[ idx ] != *String::WHITESPACE) && !is.ios::fail() ) {
    ++idx;
    is.get();
    data[ idx ] = s[ idx ];
  }
  return is;
}
```

When this new code is executed however it just gets stuck in a loop of user input. So how do I use is.get() to read in the data character by character but not wait for more user input? Or should I perhaps be using something other than .get()?

Comment: "I know that this code works". I doubt it. It's trying to `delete` something that's very likely not a pointer.

Comment: There was a copy-paste mistake there. the line is actually delete &s, which then properly displays the given string after reading it in.

Comment: No, there's no way `delete &s` is a good idea either.

Comment: Note that what you are doing with operator>> is *overloading*, not *overriding*.

Comment: That function cannot assume that s was dynamically allocated or is not an element in an array of strings.  Whey would you delete in in any case!?  Apart from that if it were a copy-paste error, why not edit the question?

Comment: I think you should also rename some of those variables, we have code complete now, no need for shortened variable names. Your teacher will thank you for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to be doing anything with the character you get from the stream

```
istream& operator>>(istream &is, String &s) {
  char data[ String::BUFF_INC ];
  int idx = 0;
  data[ 0 ] = is.get();
  while( (data[ idx ] != *String::WHITESPACE) && !is.ios::fail() ) {
    ++idx;
    is.get();              // you don't do anything with this
    data[ idx ] = s[ idx ]; // you're copying the string into the buffer
  }
  return is;
}
```

So it checks whether the string s contains a whitespace, not whether you read a whitespace from the stream.

Comment: You are right, thank you! I edited the code to add what is returned from .get() to data. How do I tell the loop to break out when it has reached the end of the string? Right now the code just hangs unless there is a whitespace in the string, at which point it breaks. Shouldn't !is.ios::fail() trigger when the end of the string is reached because it sets eof()?

Comment: @user502344  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios/fail/ "The function returns true if either the failbit or the badbit is set. At least one of these flags is set when some error **other than reaching the End-Of-File** occurs during an input operation."

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
istream& operator>>(istream &is, String &s)
{
    std::string  buffer;
    is >> buffer;           // This reads 1 white space separated word.

    s.data = buffer.c_str();
    return is;
}
```

Commenting on your original code:

```
istream& operator>>(istream &is, String &s)
{
  char data[ String::BUFF_INC ];
  is >> data;   // Will work. But prone to buffer overflow.


  delete s;    // This line is definately wrong.
               // s is not a pointer so I don;t know what deleting it would do.

  s = data;    // Assume assignment operator is defined.
               // for your class that accepts a C-String
  return s;
}
```

Using the second version as a base:

```
istream& operator>>(istream &is, String &s)
{
  std::vector<char> data;

  char first;
  // Must ignore all the white space before the word
  for(first = is.get(); String::isWhiteSpace(first) && is; first = is.get())
  {}

  // If we fond a non space first character
  if (is && !String::isWhiteSpace(first))
  {
      data.push_back(first);
  }


  // Now get values while white space is false
  char next;
  while( !String::isWhiteSpace(next = is.get()) && is)
  {
      // Note we test the condition of the stream in the loop
      // This is because is.get() may fail (with eof() or bad()
      // So we test it after each get.
      //
      // Normally you would use >> operator but that ignores spaces.
      data.push_back(next);
  }
  // Now assign it to your String object
  data.push_back('\0');
  s.data = data;
  return is;
}
```

Comment: The OP mentioned that he is required to read individual characters by himself.